# Is it possible to pass data to Oracle Trigger?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, session, triggers

I use Oracle Trigger to log all UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE query, is it possible to pass php session_id to Oracle Trigger ? like append in the query, possible ? how to ?

Comment: Triggers aren't directly accessed, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [contexts](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/create_context.html). So right after you have connected to database - you specify the php session id to context and read it from the context in trigger.

Comment: The CLIENT_INFO attribute of the default USERENV context is work considering. You set it with a calls to DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO

Comment: @Gary Myers: oh, cool. Moved from such indeterministic things not long ago though.